# if !isset multiple OR conditions

Tags: php

I cannot get this to work for the life of me, it is PHP.

```
<?php
 if (!isset($_POST['ign']) || ($_POST['email'])) {

  echo "Please enter all of the values!";
    }

 else {

   echo "Thanks, " . $_POST['ign'] . ", you will recieve an email when the site is         complete!";

    }
    ?>
```

I've also tried using !isset twice.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question you should accept it as the answer! : )

Answer (score 23):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) accepts more than just oneparameter, so just pass as many variables as you need to check:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) {
        echo "Please enter all of the values!";
    }else{    
        echo "Thanks,". $_POST['ign'].", you will receive an email when the site is complete!";   
    }
?>
```

You could use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) as well, but it doesn't accept more than a variable at a time.

Comment: Are you sure you check OR condition? If both entries are required, you should use AND

Comment: What I understood from the output text is that the user is looking for a way of checking all the required fields. Sure, it may be confusing, given the question's title.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved this issue:

```
$expression = $_POST['ign'] || $_POST['email'] ;
if (!isset($expression) {
    echo "Please enter all of the values!";
}
else {
     echo "Thanks, " . $_POST['ign'] . ", you will recieve an email when the site is                              
              complete!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way I know of:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) {//do the fields exist
    if($_POST['ign'] && $_POST['email']){ //do the fields contain data
        echo ("Thanks, " . $_POST['ign'] . ", you will recieve an email when the site is complete!");
    }
    else {
        echo ("Please enter all of the values!");
    }
}
else {
    echo ("Error in form data!");
}
?>
```

Edit: Corrected the code to show the form data and empty values errors seperatly.

Explanation:  The first if statement checks that the submitted form contained two fields,  ign and email. This is done to stop the second if statement , in the case that ign or email weren't passed in at all, from throwing an error(message would be  printed to server logs).  The second if statement checks the values of ign and email to see if they contain data.

Comment: This worked but I don't understand why... Isnt the first if statement already covering the second one?

Comment: @user1138090 The first if verifies that the form data contains both fields. The second if verifies that the fields are not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
 if (!isset($_POST['ign']) || isset($_POST['email'])) {
  echo "Please enter all of the values!";
    }
 else {
   echo "Thanks, " . $_POST['ign'] . ", you will recieve an email when the site is         complete!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: does this actually work? it will echo all values if just one parameter is met?

Answer (score 0):

```
 isset($_POST['ign'],$_POST['email']));
```

and then check for the empty values.

Comment: isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. You are passing in an expression that evaluates to boolean. In other words, this doesn't work the way one might think.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) {
        echo "Please enter all of the values!";
    } else {
        echo "Thanks, " . $_POST['ign'] . ", you will receive an email when the site is complete!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the additional Round bracket on the end of if (!isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])

Should be

if (!isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) {

Comment: This solution was posted over 3 years earlier by the top voted answer - Diego's.

Answer (score -1):

When you work with POST, use `empty()`. because when your form send data. It async null for empty input!
best way is that:

```
 if ((!isset($_POST['ign']) || empty($_POST['ign'])) &&
     (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
```

YES! It's Ugly...

So you can use:

```
<?php
 if ( checkInput($_POST['ign']) || checkInput($_POST['email']) ) {

  echo "Please enter all of the values!";
    }

 else {

   echo "Thanks, " . $_POST['ign'] . ", you will recieve an email when the site is         complete!";

    }

 function checkInput($input){
     return ( !isset($input) || empty($input) );
 }
?>
```

Comment: This returns "Warning: Undefined array key" if the key isn't set.

Comment: Hi @RichardMuthwill. Yes, it just show warning, but work properly.
Never show any error level to your client! Errors should be save as a log and check. So you can set `php.ini` or add this line to first line of your code: `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Answer (score -2):

```
// if any of this session is set then
if (isset($_SESSION['tusername']) || isset($_SESSION['student_login'])) {
  it will return true;
} else {
  it will return false;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly for readability.