# Validate Email Error

Tags: php, validation

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) {
    if($_POST['ign'] && $_POST['email']){

    }
    else {
        echo ("Please enter all of the values!");
    }
}
else {
    echo ("Error in form data!");
}
if((FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL($_POST['email'] == TRUE))) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo ("Thanks, " . htmlentities($_POST['ign']) . ", you will recieve an email when the site is complete!");
}
else {
    echo "Failure!";
}

// insert email and ign into database
?>
```

Is this going to work correctly? First time doing something completely from scratch lol!

OK! I have changed it. What about this? Should I also do the empty thing?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) {
    if($_POST['ign'] && $_POST['email']){
    echo "Please fill out all of the fields!";
        die;
}
if(var_filter($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo ("Thanks, " . htmlentities($_POST['ign']) . ", you will recieve an email when the site is complete!");
}
else {
    echo "Your email was invalid!";
}

// insert email and ign into database
?>
```

Comment: +1 for looking into the filter functions for validation on a first attempt!

Comment: No it's not going to work. But before you ask if it does, you should execute the code and try to fix the errors it returns. Understanding the errors and fixing them aids your future programming greatly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if !isset multiple OR conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784584/if-isset-multiple-or-conditions)

Comment: `filter_var`, not `var_filter`. And yes, also do the empty check :-) That's also going to mess up because of a couple of missing braces; try indenting your code more consistently and you will see you need a close brace after the die and one after the filter_var condition.

Comment: @cbuckley cool thanks a ton. Guess I've got it all figured out now. Will probably have like 20 more questions tonight though rofl xD

Answer (score 0):

Use built in functions, don't re-invent the wheel:

```
if(filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  echo "Mail is valid!";
}
```

WHY IS YOUR FUNCTION NAME ALL CAPS?

...and do you see the difference between this...

```
if(func($_POST['email'] == TRUE)){
```

and this..

```
if(func($_POST['email']) == TRUE){
```

?

Comment: **Word of warning**: This will validate something like `foo@example` (no TLD) as it is a valid (albeit local) e-mail address. Look at combining with [chkdnsrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) to validate the domain part of the address.

Comment: No, lol. I also thought FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL was its on function... i wasn't using filter_var.

Comment: @user1138090: have a look at the order of the parentheses. They are subtly different.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of mistakes there. Here's what you should be doing:

```
// First check if both fields are present. Usually there is no point in doing this
// because the next check will also catch this case, but you had it so I put it in too.
if (!isset($_POST['ign'], $_POST['email'])) { 
    echo ("Error in form data!"); 
    die; // or something else
}

// Then check if both values are non-"empty" (you might want to look at the docs for
// an explanation of what this means exactly).
if (empty($_POST['ign']) || empty($_POST['email'])) { 
    echo ("Please enter all of the values!"); 
    die; // or something else
}

// Finally, validate the email. DO NOT COMPARE WITH true!
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Failure!"; 
    die; // etc
}

echo ("Thanks, " . htmlentities($_POST['ign']) . ", blah blah!");
```

Comment: The OP's initial isset() call is perfectly valid. It seems the student has taught the master about the [function signature of isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) :-D

Comment: @cbuckley: Oops. Well, you learn something every day! Answer edited so as to not sound silly. ;-)